# What does the AT symbol mean in KOTLIN

Tags: kotlin, symbols

What does the @ symbol mean in this code clip?

Learning

```
  @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME)
    fun onResume() {
        log.i(LOG_TAG, "OnResume")
    }
```

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/annotations.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@:

- introduces an annotation
- introduces or references a loop label
- introduces or references a lambda label
- references a 'this' expression from an outer scope
- references an outer superclass

As noted by @jb-nizet, in this case it seems to represent an annotation, which allows a class to monitor the component's lifecycle status.

Via:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html